# node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v83-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown/opus.node: invalid ELF header

Tags: node.js, github, discord.js, node-modules, opus

So I'm making a Discord Bot that relays audio from one voice channel to another, and I ran into a bug.  Console said it couldn't find the `opus.node` file since I'm hosting the bot off of GitHub.  So I changed the `module_path` value in `node_modules/@discordjs/opus/package.json` to exactly the path.  It then said I had to add a substitution string for `napi_build_version`, so I did. Then it gave me another error saying that there was an invalid ELF header, and that it couldn't find `node-opus` or `opusscript`.

```
node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v83-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown/opus.node: invalid ELF header
(a few console.log lines not from errors)
Error: Cannot find module 'node-opus'
(some other error lines)
Error: Cannot find module 'opusscript'
```

Below is the code that I think the error is originating from.

```
function record(userid, connection){
    const audio = connection.receiver.createStream(userid, {end: 'manual', type: 'opus'})
    const playlist = connection.play(audio, { type: 'opus' })
}
```

Where I'm running the function from:

```
voiceChannel.members.forEach((member) => {
        if (member.id !== client.user.id && !ignore.includes(member.id)){
             record(member.id, connection);
        }
    })
```

and what the variables' values are:

```
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
```

**Note: I can't run code in the GitHub Console(the console is just a log)**
If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding

```
- run: npm install @discordjs/opus
```

to the `.yml` file above the

```
- run: node index.js
```

This way it installs the module for the system it uses.